# "No execution and no error messages when running 'dqn.test' "

Tags: python, keras, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym, q-learning

When running the code scores = dqn.test(env, nb_episodes=100, visualize=False), I am encountering an issue where the execution takes a long time without producing any output or error messages. The code is intended to test the performance of the dqn agent on the env environment for 100 episodes, without visualizing the gameplay.

Despite waiting for a considerable amount of time, there is no visible progress or indication of any error occurring. The code seems to be stuck or taking an excessive amount of time to complete.

I would appreciate any insights or suggestions on what might be causing this issue and how to resolve it.

```
import gym
from gym import spaces
import numpy as np
import random

class EnergyOptimizationEnv(gym.Env):
    def __init__(self):
        # Définir les actions possibles : éteindre ou ne rien faire
        self.action_space = spaces.Discrete(2)
        
        # Définir l'espace d'observation : consommation énergétique
        self.observation_space = spaces.Box(low=0, high=10000, shape=(9,), dtype=np.float32)
        
        # Définir les seuils de consommation pour chaque appareil
        self.energy_ranges = {
            'lamp': (15, 100),
            'tv': (200, 400),
            'fridge': (1000, 2000)
        }
        
        # Définir le seuil critique de consommation énergétique
        self.energy_threshold = 10000
        
        # Initialiser l'état (consommation énergétique de chaque appareil)
        self.state = np.zeros(9)
        
        # Initialiser les compteurs d'appareils allumés
        self.num_lamps_on = 0
        self.num_tvs_on = 0
        self.num_fridges_on = 0
    
    def step(self, action):
        # Mettre à jour l'état en fonction de l'action choisie
        self.update_state(action)
        
        # Calculer la récompense en fonction de l'état actuel
        reward = self.calculate_reward()
        
        # Vérifier si le seuil critique de consommation est dépassé
        done = self.check_threshold()
        
        # Retourner l'état, la récompense, le booléen "done" et des informations supplémentaires
        info = {
            'num_lamps_on': self.num_lamps_on,
            'lamp_energy_consumption': self.state[0],
            'num_tvs_on': self.num_tvs_on,
            'tv_energy_consumption': self.state[1],
            'num_fridges_on': self.num_fridges_on,
            'fridge_energy_consumption': self.state[2]
        }
        return self.state, reward, done, info
    
    def update_state(self, action):
        # Mettre à jour l'état en fonction de l'action choisie
        if action == 1:  # Allumer un appareil aléatoire
            device = random.choice(list(self.energy_ranges.keys()))
            energy_range = self.energy_ranges[device]
            energy_consumption = random.uniform(energy_range[0], energy_range[1])
            if device == 'lamp':
                self.num_lamps_on += 1
                self.state[0] += energy_consumption
                self.state[3] = self.num_lamps_on
                self.state[4] = self.state[0]
            elif device == 'tv':
                self.num_tvs_on += 1
                self.state[1] += energy_consumption
                self.state[5] = self.num_tvs_on
                self.state[6] = self.state[1]
            elif device == 'fridge':
                self.num_fridges_on += 1
                self.state[2] += energy_consumption
                self.state[7] = self.num_fridges_on
                self.state[8] = self.state[2]
        else:  # Ne rien faire
            self.state[3] = self.num_lamps_on
            self.state[4] = self.state[0]
            self.state[5] = self.num_tvs_on
            self.state[6] = self.state[1]
            self.state[7] = self.num_fridges_on
            self.state[8] = self.state[2]
    
    def calculate_reward(self):
        # Calculer la récompense en fonction de l'état actuel
        if np.sum(self.state) <= self.energy_threshold:
            reward = 1
        else:
            reward = -1
        return reward
    
    def check_threshold(self):
        # Vérifier si le seuil critique de consommation est dépassé
        return np.sum(self.state) > self.energy_threshold
    
    def reset(self):
        # Réinitialiser l'état (consommation énergétique de chaque appareil)
        self.state = np.zeros(9)
        
        # Réinitialiser les compteurs d'appareils allumés
        self.num_lamps_on = 0
        self.num_tvs_on = 0
        self.num_fridges_on = 0
        
        # Retourner l'état initial
        return self.state

import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Flatten
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers.legacy import Adam
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Flatten
from rl.agents import DQNAgent
from rl.policy import GreedyQPolicy
from rl.memory import SequentialMemory
from rl.agents import DQNAgent
from rl.callbacks import ModelIntervalCheckpoint, FileLogger
from rl.policy import LinearAnnealedPolicy, EpsGreedyQPolicy
from rl.memory import SequentialMemory

env = EnergyOptimizationEnv()
states = env.observation_space.shape
actions = env.action_space.n

def build_model(states, actions):
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Flatten(input_shape=(1,) + states))
    model.add(Dense(24, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(24, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(actions, activation='linear'))
    return model

model = build_model(states, actions)
model.summary()

def build_agent(model, actions):
    policy = LinearAnnealedPolicy(EpsGreedyQPolicy(), attr='eps', value_max=1, value_min=0.1, value_test=0.05,nb_steps=500)
    memory = SequentialMemory(limit=10000, window_length=1)
    dqn = DQNAgent(model=model, memory=memory, policy=policy, enable_double_dqn=True,nb_actions=actions, gamma=.98, nb_steps_warmup=100, target_model_update=1e-2)
    return dqn

dqn = build_agent(model, actions)
dqn.compile(Adam(lr=1e-3), metrics=['mae'])
dqn.fit(env, nb_steps=30000, log_interval=1000, nb_max_episode_steps=50, visualize=False, verbose=1)

scores = dqn.test(env, nb_episodes=100, visualize=False)
print(np.mean(scores.history['episode_reward']))
```

In attempting to address the issue, I have tried the following:

Ensuring that the necessary libraries and dependencies are properly installed and up to date.
Verifying that the dqn agent and env environment are set up correctly and compatible with each other.
Reviewing the code and its documentation to ensure that I am using the dqn.test function correctly with the appropriate parameters.
Experimenting with various policies, including the GreedyQPolicy and BoltzmannQPolicy, to assess their impact on the execution time.
Taking into account that I am working in Google Colab, considering the potential limitations and resource constraints of the platform.
Attempting to reduce the number of episodes to a smaller value (e.g., 10) to see if the issue persists with a lower workload.
Implementing a separate model for Q-value prediction using the code snippet provided:

```
from rl.policy import GreedyQPolicy
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Input, Reshape

scores = []
num_episodes = 100

policy = GreedyQPolicy()  # Créer une politique GreedyQPolicy

# Construire un modèle séparé pour la prédiction des valeurs Q
input_shape = env.observation_space.shape
inputs = Input(shape=input_shape)
reshape = Reshape((1,) + input_shape)(inputs)
q_values = dqn.model(reshape)
q_model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=q_values)

for episode in range(num_episodes):
    state = env.reset()
    done = False
    episode_reward = 0
    
    while not done:
        q_values = q_model.predict(np.expand_dims(state, axis=0))
        action = policy.select_action(q_values[0])
        next_state, reward, done, _ = env.step(action)
        episode_reward += reward
        state = next_state
    
    scores.append(episode_reward)

average_score = np.mean(scores)
print(average_score)
```

However, despite these efforts, the issue persists. I expected the dqn.test function to execute within a reasonable time frame and provide the desired results, including the scores for the 100 test episodes. I did not expect the execution to be excessively slow or to encounter a lack of output or error messages.

I am seeking guidance on how to troubleshoot and resolve this issue, or any alternative approaches that can be used to test the performance of the agent in a more efficient manner.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. The solution that helped me is to add these parameters to my **dqn.test** function: `action_repetition` and `nb_max_episode_steps` (https://github.com/keras-rl/keras-rl/blob/master/rl/core.py).

- **action_repetition** (integer): Number of times the agent repeats the same action without observing the environment again. Setting this to a value > 1 can be useful if a single action only has a very small effect on the environment.
- **nb_max_episode_steps** (integer): Number of steps per episode that the agent performs before automatically resetting the environment. Set to `None` if each episode should run (potentially indefinitely) until the environment signals a terminal state.

For example, here's my code modification:

```
scores = dqn.test(
    env,
    nb_episodes=100,
    action_repetition=1,  # edited
    nb_max_episode_steps=200,   # edited
    visualize=False,
    verbose=1
)
```